# Cant Edit Form Even after Using OnChange Listener and updating the state

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui, react-state

Unable to edit the form even after using value attribute and updating the state.Im using Semantic UI Form to display the form. I am Using OnChange event listener and value and name attribute , eventhough icant edit form.I have provided my code below

```
 const { PostsStore } = useStore();
 const { CreatePost, selectedPost, EditPost } = PostsStore;
 const InitialState = selectedPost ?? {
   id: "",
   displayName: "",
   Price: 0,
   description: "",
   sizes: "",
   Image: null,
 };
 const [post, SetPost] = useState(InitialState);
 const handleSubmit = () => {
   console.log(post);
   if (post.id) {
     EditPost(post);
   } else {
     CreatePost(post);
   }
 };

 const handleInputChange = (
   event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>
 ) => {
   const { name, value } = event.target;
   SetPost({ ...post, [name]: value });
 };
 return (
   <Segment clearing>
     <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
       <Form.Input
         placeholder="DisplayName"
         value={selectedPost?.displayName}
         name="dislayName"
         onChange={(e) =>handleInputChange(e)}
       />
       <Form.Input
         placeholder="Price"
         value={selectedPost?.Price}
         name="Price"
         onChange={handleInputChange}
       />
       <Form.TextArea
         placeholder="Description"
         value={selectedPost?.description}
         name="description"
         onChange={handleInputChange}
       />
       <Form.Input
         placeholder="Sizes"
         value={selectedPost?.sizes}
         name="sizes"
         onChange={handleInputChange}
       />
       <Button floated="right" type="submit" positive content="Submit" />
       <Button floated="right" type="button" color="red" content="Cancel" />
     </Form>
   </Segment>
 );
};

export default PostForm;
```

Comment: You should use "post" state in the form inputs, not the "selectedPost" prop, did you try it?
For example value={post?.description}

Comment: @FatihTurgut I used post?.description but no luck. Form is still non-editable